# The Best way to write custom exception name in java

Tags: java, exception, naming

I just wonder about best way to write custom exception name, like if I have user and i want make exception for add and delete and update, what is better using names like :

```
UserAddException
UserUpdateException
UserRemoveException or UserDeleteException ?
```

or like:

```
UserAdditionException
UserUpdateException
UserDeletionException
```

Exception name must describe what it handle, but not sure use "verb" describe the action where exception happened or "noun" as what exception itself do.

What I want to understand here the best way that make developers understand my exception usage and what to use later, and if there is pattern or standard used for Java development in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately most answers to this will likely be opinion-based, as opposed to fact-based, thus it doesn't make a particularly good [so] question.

Comment: Instead of describing the operation that triggered the exception, it would probably be better to describe the reason: for example DuplicateUserException("can't add user because it already exists").

Comment: Since the Java Exception name reflects the `wrong` action taken by the user in the exception name. So i would prefer the exception to be like following since they contains(probably indicate) the cause of the exception

    UserAlreadyExistException - If user already exist
    UnAuthorizedUserException - If user need some rights before addition but that are not provided
    AdminUserDeleteException - If trying to delete admin user by non-admin user. Here i feel `DeletingSuperUserException` would sound more appropiate.

Comment: @Dukeling I ask about coding issue and best way, that why i asked here, and cuz i already saw alot of question like this type here, and after I google it, so I think is good idea to ask about "best" of the good and share for knowledge after I get my good answer cuz yet not sure what to do .

Comment: @GauravGupta and assylias , thank you for your comments and you have good point, but my issue that I use another sdk what give me exact reason but I build another business layer what make this not really help, becasue I get an error for add user to DB as example for any "unknown" reason for my layer, so its like something happened in ad user, then I see full stack, but in presentation layer I need to give general message after a specific.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar In that case you can use `factory pattern`, provide the message to the factory( message you received from below layer) and get the suitable Exception object generated from the factory. This Exception object will contain the message for presentation layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the second type of exception names. The reason why I would say that is because the exception: `InstantiationException` uses the noun `InstantiationException`. However, he most important thing is that you are consistent with the naming of exceptions and that the exception names give the development team a clear idea of what those exceptions indicate and their meaning. That is really the critical thing here.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do will be, use `UserManagementException` instead of too many names, and specify the exact cause of it in some message or error code defined additionally in the class.

Comment: Thanks, I would like this way, but I asked to do this way, we need this way in details for another business we want to do.

Comment: Well, seems i'll use the way that u wrote, but yet I need to name constants for exceptions so, my question still need answer :)